# Domain List not populating during editing in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, domains

[image]I have created  new field "Facility_Type" to the existing feature class and applied coded value domain. but during editing domain value is not populating.

You can refer the attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Your screen shots seem to show that you have created your domain and assigned it but you have not provided your next steps or any screenshots to show that values are not populating during editing.

Comment: Dear Polygeo i have edited the question and added 2nd screen shot with editing not showing domain drop down list.

Answer (score 2):

you have set the domain of the field at table level. You are using subtype with your table and you must set domain at subtype level.

Follow this path:

Right click your FeatureClass (PW_Facilities) in ArcCatalog > Subtypes Tab > Select Pump Station subtype > set facility_type field domain to FacilityType.

Comment: Thanks Farid Cher, Reason i am using domain and subtype separately is that, same ArcSDE GDB is published on ArcGIS server to be consumed in ArcGIS viewer for flex and there when we identify the feature it doesn't show subtype description. it will only show subtype codes. that's why i am using domain and subtypes separately.

Comment: No problem with using both of them but to solve your problem with ArcMap you have to follow my answer.